# Ensamblador: Menú no me salta a la opción indicada

Tags: ensamblador, menu

Intento con numero normales o con hex para las opciones , pero cuando ingreso la opción 2 que es imprimir paridad impar , siempre me imprime es paridad par, no he podido dar con la solución de este problema, cualquier ayuda seria bienvenida , estoy usando emu8086

```
ASSUME CS:CODIGO, DS:DATOS, SS:PILA

CODIGO SEGMENT  
MOV AX,DATOS
MOV DS,AX

    inicio:  
    MOV DX ,offset texto1
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
          
    MOV DX ,offset texto2
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
          
    MOV DX ,offset texto3
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H 
                               
    MOV DX ,offset texto5
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH,01H
    INT 21H        
    CMP op,49
    JZ par
    
    CMP op,50
    JZ impar       
    par:
    
    MOV DX ,offset msg
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    JMP inicio                  
    impar:
        
    MOV DX ,offset msg2
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    JMP inicio

CODIGO ENDS

 PILA SEGMENT STACK
    DW 32 DUP (0)
PILA ENDS
DATOS SEGMENT    
   texto1 db 13,10,13,10,13, ">>MENU<<$"
   texto2 db 13,10,13,10,"1.Paridad Par$"
   texto3 db 13,10,"2.Paridad Impar$"   
   texto5 db 13,10,13,10 ,"Elija Paridad: $"
   texto6 db 13,10, "Escriba Numero: $"   
   msg db  13,10,13,10,"Paridad par$" 
   msg2 DB 13,10,13,10,"Paridad Impar$"  
   op db ?

  DATOS ENDS

  END
```

PSDT:

Estoy en la lucha intentando resolver este ejercicio

Diseñar un programa en el lenguaje ensamblador del up8088, que calcule la paridad de un número ingresado por teclado ( un dato de máximo 4 dígitos
decimales con signo). La paridad la elegirá el usuario mediante un menú en pantalla, el resultado se mostrara mediante un mensaje en pantalla. El programa
debe verificar si el dato ingresado está en el rango valido.
Ejemplo: si el usuario ingresa el número -1024 y selecciona paridad par, el programa mostrara en pantalla: “El bit de paridad par para el dato ingresado es 1”.